# C++ function to return true when pointer points to a specific polymorphic type

Tags: c++

Other languages have an "is" operator that allow this, how do I emulate this in C++ and can it be done at runtime?

Say for example,

```cpp
class A {
public:
// virtual methods..
};
class B : public A {};
class C: public A {};

A* x;
template<typename T>
bool foo(A* par); // returns true if par is of type T

int main() {

 A* b = new B();
 A* c = new C();
 x = c;

 if(foo<B>(x))
 {
  // do something
 }
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid but such things are not recommended if you want to program in an OOP way

Comment: What is the *actual* and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need to use functions (or down-/up-casts) to differentiate between objects? Can't normal polymorphism (i.e. just call functions and let the compiler/runtime handle dispatching) solve the problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A project I am currently working on has a pattern like I described in OP, I just want to execute a function to manipulate the value of `x` based on its polymorphic type.

I am not sure if there is a better design to achieve the goal..

Comment: If you need to do something that depends on dynamic type, it's probably worth considering the visitor pattern. That's the usual way of handling double dispatch in C++.

Comment: Also, if you're really using a global pointer variable, there's almost certainly room to improve the design. Avoid globals if at all possible.

Comment: @Useless OP is just a simplification, thank you for suggesting the visitor pattern though.

Comment: Do you want to check that `x` is **exactly** of type `B` (so would be false for a class B2 inheriting from B)?

Comment: `// returns true if par is of type T` - What `par`? Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, you could `dynamic_cast` and see if you have a nullpointer. A dynamic cast will return `nullptr` at runtime if the input pointed type is not compatible with the output pointed type.

```
A* b = new B();
A* c = new C();
x = c;

if(dynamic_cast<B*>(x) != nullptr)
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write

```
if (dynamic_cast<B*>(x)) {
  // ...
}
```

since it returns `nullptr` (which evaluates as `false`) if the dynamic type doesn't match.

Note that this doesn't guarantee that `B` is the most-derived type, only that it is *an* accessible base class of the most-derived type.

If you really need to distinguish between an `A*` pointing to a `B` or to some other class derived from `B`, you need instead

```
if (typeid(*x) == typeid(B))
```

---

Since you actually asked how to write the function `foo`, it's simply

```
template<typename Dynamic, typename Static>
bool foo(Static *p)
{
  return dynamic_cast<Dynamic*>(p);
}
```

or once again

```
template<typename Dynamic, typename Static>
bool foo(Static *p)
{
  return (typeid(*p) == typeid(Dynamic));
}
```

but this isn't very interesting, and the `foo<B>(x)` call is going to be less clear at the call site - to an experienced C++ developer - than writing either form directly.

---

NB. The comments suggesting that this is usually a bad idea are correct - it's generally better to use virtual dispatch to handle this kind of thing automatically.